# Power tower last digits

Tags: modular-arithmetic, problem-solving

Can anyone solve the following problem of finding the 6th last digit from the right of the decimal representation of the following number:

$6^{6^{6^{6^{6^{6}}}}}$

Essentially it means reducing this modulo $10^6$ and supposedly Chinese Remainder Theorem should be used, but I have no idea how to solve this. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We're interested in $6^x \mod 10^6$; this is determined by $6^i \mod 2^6$ and $6^i \mod 5^6$.  Mod $2^6$ it's easy: $6^x$ is divisible by $2^6$ if $x \ge 6$. $6$ is coprime to $5^6$ with multiplicative order $3125 = 5^5$ mod $5^6$.  In fact, the multiplicative order of $6$ mod $5^m$ seems to be $5^{m-1}$ (prove!). So 
$$\eqalign{6 &\equiv 1 \mod 5\cr 6^6 &\equiv 6^1 = 6 \mod 5^2\cr 6^{6^6} &\equiv 6^6 \equiv 31 \mod 5^3\cr
6^{6^{6^6}} &\equiv 6^{31} \equiv 531 \mod 5^4\cr 
6^{6^{6^{6^6}}} &\equiv 6^{531}\equiv 1156 \mod 5^5\cr
6^{6^{6^{6^{6^6}}}} &\equiv 6^{1156} \equiv 4281 \mod 5^6\cr 
}$$
and using Chinese Remainder, $$6^{6^{6^{6^{6^6}}}} \equiv 238656 \mod 10^6$$

Comment: How did you do this mod $5^n$ without calculator? For example $6^{1156}$

Comment: I did it with a computer.  It would be possible, though rather tedious, to do by hand using repeated squaring.

Comment: And this process of finding multiplicative order, does that have a name? What did you do there really?

Comment: Also I am interested in how did you reach the conclusion that $6^x$ is $0$ in mod $2^6$.

Comment: $6^x = 2^x \cdot 3^x$ is divisible by $2^x$.

Comment: How about the multiplicative order? Is that something connected to Euler's Totient Function?

Comment: See [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiplicative_order).